# fixed table with dynamic width cell

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this for days and I can't find a solution anywhere!

I have a table being used in a page and I can either not specify `table-layout` and have the ability to make one of the cells a dynamic width, however, no 'white-space' or 'overflow' can be specified.
If I set 'table-layout: fixed', then the dynamic cell width goes away but I can specify 'white-space' and 'overflow'.

I need both!  **How can I accomplish this using css only?** (boldness added for Jukka)

```html
<table style="width: 50%;">
<tr>
   <td style="width: 20px;">1</td>
   <td style='overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;'>
       here is a really long string to hide
   </td>
   <td style='width: 20px;'>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What makes you think you cannot specify 'white-space' or 'overflow' with automatic layout? Show an example of an actual case and explain exactly what you want.

Comment: @jukka because those declarations don't work if a fixed table isn't specified.  And per the original post, I'm looking to use both of those declarations along with the ability to have a dynamic width <td>.

Comment: They do. And you did not provide *anything* tangible to analyze.

Comment: That's not what any other posts on the web are stating, nor do I see it in my own project.

Comment: here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nmj0myh5/

Comment: @jukka I have provided something tangible, where's the answer? :)

Comment: Where is the question? What is the problem with the code snippet? If you actually make the string long and set `table-layout: fixed`, what is wrong with the result? In which sense should the middle column be “dynamic”, when the table width and the other column widths have been set?

Comment: @jukka I have bolded the first time the question was asked in the OP.  It was referenced again in the second comment above.  And I'll ask it again a third time.  How can I use 'white-space' and 'overflow' along with a dynamic width <td>?  Use the fiddle if needed.  The problem is when using a fixed table, the dynamic <td> goes away.  Please re-read the OP for additional info.

Comment: Bolding an obscure question and adding a personal note does not help. You have not said what “this” is.

Comment: @jukka sometimes you have to read more than one line to figure out what is going on.  I've asked the same thing three times in a row, so it appears that you are being difficult because the fiddle showed your original replies don't work.  If you have something constructive to add to resolve the problem, please speak up, otherwise this appears to be beyond your capabilities.

Comment: I have not posted any reply (answer). I have explained that there is no answerable question. Making insults won’t help you.

Comment: @jukka I don't see any insults so I'm not sure what you're referring to.  This will be my last reply to you since you are not offering any help, just wasting my time and the time of others who are viewing this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="width: 50%;">
<tbody><tr>
   <td style="width: 20px;">1</td>
   <td style="overflow: hidden;height:20px;display: block;">
       here is a really long string fdfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfdfd fdf df dfdfddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd fdfd fdfdto hide
   </td>
   <td style="width: 20px;">3</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

display:block + height:20px should help :-)

Comment: hmmm, I added both of those to the fiddle but they don't appear to resolve the problem.

Comment: do you have any other thoughts on a solution?